# ASP.NET and Entity Framework 6: 1-to-1 Relationship can't save when the child relationship does not exist yet

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I just migrated, code-first, so that a Customer model has an optional address and the address has a required customer:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
        .HasOptional(c => c.BillingAddress)
        .WithRequired(a => a.Customer);

    modelBuilder.Entity<CustomerBillingAddress>()
        .HasKey(a => a.CustomerId);
```

This works great if I create the Customer from this point on.

Any customer that existed before adding the address - I can't edit, add the address details, and post back to Edit because my ModelState is invalid with a CustomerId required error on the billingAddress.

I've tried testing the value and setting the addresses id to match the customer before testing ModelState.IsValid but this doesn't seem to work.

I could surely just nuke the db/migrations and re-do it or update my 2 test customers to have a blank billing address to get around this.

But..I would like to know what's going on.

Here's relevant code

```
public class CustomerBillingAddress
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public long CustomerId { get; set; }

    public string Street { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Street 2")]
    public string Street2 { get; set; }

    public string City { get; set; }

    public string State { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Postal")]
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }

    public Customer Customer { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public string Location => City + ", " + State;
}
```

The Edit View does have the hidden fields:

```
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CustomerId)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.BillingAddress.CustomerId)
```

relevant controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "CustomerId,BillingName, Name,PhysicalAddress, BillingAddress, Active")] Customer customer)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Entry(customer).State = EntityState.Modified;
        if (customer.PhysicalAddress != null)
        {
            db.Entry(customer.PhysicalAddress).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
        if (customer.BillingAddress != null)
        {
            db.Entry(customer.BillingAddress).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(customer);
}
```

Comment: Can you capture the content of the ModelState?

Comment: Yes, 1 error, CustomerId required on the BillingAddress.  The reason being there's not one yet, the hidden form tag sets it to 0.

Comment: You must use ViewModel to do make your life easier